# Sort Arrays in Object: Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an object which contains varies keys & their values as array.

Ex.

```
Obj = {
    adj_qty :[10,50], //With close to 50k elements.
    attr_no :["DNF","DNF"],
    qty :["10","50"],
    art_code :["8903ABC4793","8903328757534"],
    cost :[377.95,241.75]
}
```

Now i wanted sort these all array on the basis of key `art_code`.

Is there any best possible way to sort these kind of arrays?

**NOTE**: Each array has around `50k` array elements. so i used this way to structured all of these in single object instead of object in array.

Thanks, Regards.

Comment: Why don't you make an array of objects instead of an object of arrays?  Also, what order shall `art_code` sort the elements of the arrays (e.g by comparison of each character from start to finish, numeric comparison(?), etc.?

Comment: This is very inefficient with your current data structure. As @Qantas 94 Heavy mentioned, you can use array of objects and it will help you sorting easily.

Comment: you should link somehow inner arrays to sort all of that by a key of one of them. Otherwise will get a mess. Better change the structure.

Comment: Each array has around `50K` element size. If i structured array of object then this would repeating my keys for `50K` times. that's why i prefer this way..

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, @tejas, @i100: don't you guys think about repeating of `50k` keys of object in each array element??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sortStack = []
  ,       len = Obj.art_code.length
  ;

// Sort by art_code, storing the sorting results
Obj.art_code.sort( function( a, b ){
    var res = (a>b)?-1:1; // This controls the sorting order
    sortStack.push( res );

    return res;
});

// sort everything else in the same order
for( var n in Obj ){
    if( !Obj.hasOwnProperty( n ) || ( n === 'art_code' ) ){ continue; }

    var ary = sortStack.slice();

    // sort anything that is an array of the same length
    Obj[n].sort
      && ( Obj[n].length === len )
      && Obj[n].sort( function(){ return ary.shift(); } );
}
```